# Setting up pfsense on a small business network for firewall use

Tags: windows, firewall, router, switch, pfsense

I have approximately 20 machines that will all be on the same subnet with a pfsense firewall. I have no experience with pfsense, so I am just starting out.

I have the following configuration:

[image]

The WAN is a [surfboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AJHDZSI) modem. The LAN is the pfsense dedicated machine. The OPT1 is a wireless router.

Topology:
[image]

The [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/) machine is able to ping externally, while the client is not. The client is able to ping within the subnet.

What am I doing wrong? **How do I get the client to be able to ping externally?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you are receiving your IP from the DHCP on the client and it knows that 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.1 is the default gateway. You may have to ipconfig /release renew.
2. Confirm on the wireless router that it does not have the DHCP server enabled, this would more than likely try to send the traffic out through it's wan port. And I assume that the wan port is not how the wireless router is connected.